# Git bash Command not found

Tags: winforms, git-bash

I am trying to install local gridstudio using git bash in windows 10. When I run `./run.sh`, I got the following

```sh
./run.sh: line 5: docker: command not found
./run.sh: line 11: docker: command not found
```

Then I went to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, the browser said it can't reach this page. I am doing exactly what this installation tells to do.

https://github.com/ricklamers/gridstudio/wiki/Installation

How do I fix this issue?

the gridstudio has been successfully downloaded and resolved

Here is the log:

```sh
    MINGW64 ~
    $ git clone https://github.com/ricklamers/gridstudio
    Cloning into 'gridstudio'...
    remote: Enumerating objects: 1844, done.
    remote: Counting objects: 100% (1844/1844), done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (782/782), done.
    remote: Total 1844 (delta 1021), reused 1782 (delta 967), pack-reused 0
    Receiving objects: 100% (1844/1844), 127.51 MiB | 68.00 KiB/s, done.
    Resolving deltas: 100% (1021/1021), done.

    MINGW64 ~
    $ cd gridstudio && ./run.sh
    ./run.sh: line 5: docker: command not found
    ./run.sh: line 11: docker: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error shows that you do not have Docker installed. Try installing it using the link provided below the Grid Studio instructions (ie. https://docs.docker.com/install/)

Comment: Thank you! I install it and fix it.

Comment: Great! Can you mark my answer as correct if it fixed your problem?